# How to show and hide input based on other inputs value - no JQuery

Tags: javascript

I have a form with two number inputs (`betsHome` and `betsAway`) and two radio inputs (`widgetHome` and `wigetAway`). By default, the radio inputs are hidden. I want them to be visible when the two number inputs have the same value, using only JavaScript.

Here is my current script :

```
betHome.addEventListener('input', function (ev) {
    hideOrShowWidget(ev, betAway, widgetHome, widgetAway)
});
betAway.addEventListener('input', function (ev) {
    hideOrShowWidget(ev, betHome, widgetHome, widgetAway)
});

function hideOrShowWidget(event, other, widgetHome, widgetAway) {
if (event.value === other.value) {
    widgetHome.style.visibility = 'visible';
    widgetAway.style.visibility = 'visible';
} else {
    widgetHome.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    widgetAway.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

But somehow it doesn't work : console keeps sending this alert *TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'other.value')*

Can you help me figure where the problem is please ?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and edit your question so that the code is inside of a "code snippet" so that we can run it, right here in your question. This also makes it easier for us to provide you with a working answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply select the values contained in each input box then check like you did if they're equal. If so you can apply the appropriate CSS properties to the radio boxes.

Here is the code:

```js
betHome.addEventListener('input', function() {
  hideOrShowWidget();
});
betAway.addEventListener('input', function() {
  hideOrShowWidget();
});

function hideOrShowWidget() {

  let input1 = document.querySelector('#betHome').value
  let input2 = document.querySelector('#betAway').value

  if (input1 === input2) {
    radio1.style.visibility = 'visible';
    radio2.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    radio1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    radio2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

```css
#radio1, #radio2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>BetHome</div>
<input type="text" id="betHome">
<input type="radio" id="radio2"> 


<br />
<div>BetAway</div>
<input type="text" id="betAway">
<input type="radio" id="radio1">
```